# greek beta code in \footnotes

Tags: footnotes, betababel

To write quotations in ancient greek I used tu put

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}
```

in the preamble.
Last year I changed my computer to a Mac and I started getting error messages like:
`Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language polutonikogreek yet.`

Now I use:

```
\usepackage[polutonikogreek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{betababel}
```

as suggested in a post here.

It works fine in the text , but in footnotes I get the error message:

```
Package betababel Error: 'J' and 'j' aren't valid characters in BetaCode! You shouldn't use them, because they can make betababel interrupt. Please remove them from your source or replace them by 'S' or 's'.

See the betababel package documentation for explanation.
```

Even if there is no j or J in the text!

Can somebody help me in getting the footnotes right?
(I am extremely weak in Latex, so the simpler the better...)

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12 pt] {article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{betababel}
\begin{document}

bla bla  \footnote{\bcode {E(/TOIMOI A)EI\ PRO\S A)POLOGI/AN PANTI\ TW=| AI)TOU=NTI U(MA=S LO/GON PERI\ TH=S E)N U(MI=N E)LPI/DOS}} 
  bla 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses.

Comment: I'd say it's a bug in `betababel`, which uses internally the sequence `JJJJJJ` for some purpose I don't know.